# assign only numeric value to variable in unix

Tags: bash, grep

In bash script I am taking command line input in alphanumeric values. 
example: D7, 12D 
I want to assign these value to some variable but I want only numeric values to be assigned. In above example value should be assigned as 7 and 12

In linux it can be done by

```
echo "D7" |grep -o '[0-9]*'
```

I want this should work for both linux,unix servers. Above command doesnt work on solaris box.

Thanks for help

~Ankit

Comment: You want [GNU grep](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/66416/52050). The only reason Oracle doesn't change it (AFAIK), is because it would break existing Solaris behavior. Next, try it on AIX, HP-UX, the BSD(s) and Minix. Good luck!

Comment: Are the letters always confined to a suffix or prefix, or could you get a value like `14D7`, in which case should that be treated as `14`, `7`, or `147`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While this doesn't directly answer your question about `grep` in different environments, you can use `sed` for this:

```
echo "D7"  | sed 's/[^0-9]//g'
```

`s/[^0-9]//g` says "Replace any thing that isn't a number with nothing"

Comment: Well, sure; you could also do that. But OP was asking about grep behavior not being consistent. :)

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Oh! I didn't read that far. I always got in trouble in school for not reading all of the instructions before jumping into the solution. I feel like I should leave this up here since `sed` may provide an alternate to the oddball implementations of grep in solaris and all that.